# Python encoding. How to decode tecnolog&iacute;a

Tags: python, encoding

I am receiving input from a form using django. The imput text writes "tecnología". In django, I need to find the text in another string, but I receive it as "tecnolog&iacute;a" . How do I turn back

tecnolog&iacute;a

into

"tecnología"

Have tried string.decode() without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you could use an external library, I suggest [ftfy](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), for example:

```
import ftfy

result = ftfy.fix_text('tecnolog&iacute;a')
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
tecnología
```

As an alternative you could use the built-in module [html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html) in **Python 3.5+**:

```
import html

print(html.unescape("tecnolog&iacute;a"))
```

**Output**

```
tecnología
```

In **Python 2.7** you can use [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/htmlparser.html):

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

h = HTMLParser()
print(h.unescape("tecnolog&iacute;a"))
```

Comment: Tried using ftfy but it didnt let me install the latest version cause it is incompatible with my version of python, 2.7.12 . The version I could install is 4.4.3 gives me a `This isn't unicode` error. ... Maybe I will upgrade to python 3 cause I am tired of unicode errors. Thanks for that python 3 solution.

Comment: @AlejandroVeintimilla Updated the answer! Now includes a solution for Python 2.7